# How get image from FormData to Rails API and saves in ActiveStorage

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-native

I am trying to send a FormData object from my React Native app to my Rails API. 
I am using react-native-image-crop-picker to pick the image from gallery and store the image object in my state:

```
 ImagePicker.openPicker({
      multiple: true,
      cropping: true,
      includeBase64: true,
      compressImageMaxHeight: 1080,
      compressImageMaxWidth: 1080,
    })
      .then(selectedImages => {
        selectedImages.map(image => {

          let prefix;
          let ext;

          [prefix, ext] = image.filename.split(".");
          ext = ext.toLowerCase() === "heic" ? "jpg" : ext;

          const upload = {
            uri: image.path,
            type: image.mime,
            name: `${prefix}.${ext}`,
          };

          this.setState(prevState => ({
            event: {
              ...prevState.event,
              images: [...prevState.event.images, upload],
            },
          }));        

        });
      })
      .catch(error => {

      });
```

Then i create a FormData object to send yo my Rails API:

```
 const data = new FormData();

 data.append("name", event.name);
 data.append("description", event.description);
 data.append("date", event.date);
 data.append("time", event.time);
 data.append("images", event.images[0]);
```

My api successfully receives que request:
`Parameters: {"event"=>{"_parts"=>[["event[name]", ""], ["event[description]", ""], ["event[date]", ""], ["event[time]", ""], ["event[images]", {"uri"=>"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6226B812-CDEC-4994-A864-0A91EE8C44B3/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/BFC043EC-D33F-4E07-BBEA-634CE5DE8A3F.jpg", "type"=>"image/jpeg", "name"=>"IMG_7142.jpg"}]]}}`

Now, how can i recover this image and saves directly in my Rails ActiveStorage?
I am trying to directly attach the image object: `{"uri"=>"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6226B812-CDEC-4994-A864-0A91EE8C44B3/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/BFC043EC-D33F-4E07-BBEA-634CE5DE8A3F.jpg", "type"=>"image/jpeg", "name"=>"IMG_7142.jpg"}` to my model, but i am getting the current exception: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to save the new associated avatar_attachment.):`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see that you have multiple images to attach. 
If you've already gone through the [documentation](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html), I believe you must have already setup active storage by now.

In your model do you have `has_many_attached :images`? note that images could've been something else or just about any name.

I was able to retrieve the image name by doing the following (but I doubt if it will work for your purpose):

```
hash = {"uri"=>"/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/6226B812-CDEC-4994-A864-0A91EE8C44B3/tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/BFC043EC-D33F-4E07-BBEA-634CE5DE8A3F.jpg", "type"=>"image/jpeg", "name"=>"IMG_7142.jpg"}

hash['uri'].split('/')[-1]

=> "BFC043EC-D33F-4E07-BBEA-634CE5DE8A3F.jpg"
```

If the above route is how you want to go and you are sure that it will work this way, then you need to do something like:

`@your_model.images.attach(io: File.open("#{hash['uri']}"), filename: "#{hash['uri'].split('/')[-1]}")`

You can find here a complete tutorial on how this should actually work here - https://medium.com/@ashley_foster/react-native-image-uploads-with-activestorage-ec4898317a82

Give it a try and if you get stuck along the way, you can drop a comment or edit/update your question.

Comment: I am already managing the `has_many_attached :images`.
The problem with this tutorial is that teaches how to do but using the base64 image, which increases request size in 33%. I want to do simply sending the file by FormData. I can make it work on Postman, but sending the image from the app it looks like that i am not sending the image but only his path itself

Comment: There's a possibility that this will work, have you tried it? 

`@your_model.images.attach(io: File.open("#{hash['uri']}"), filename: "#{hash['uri'].split('/')[-1]}")`

However, if it doesn't work, I advise you to get the above tutorial to work and then worry about optimizing the size of the image afterward, that step is usually the easiest when you get there.

Comment: Yes, i tried but dind't work as expected. For now i am using the tutorial way and it is working as well. Thank you!